# Find Command: File Path vs -name Argument

Tags: bash, shell, find, wildcards

I'm currently building a script to handle some files in a directory. In the first example, I use the find command and pass a directory in as the argument. In the second I instead use the -name switch on the find command to pass the desired file-name. Can someone however explain to me the difference between the two below? As they produce exactly the same output:

`find dump* -type f -mtime +5 | xargs ls -ltrh`

`find $dir -type f -name "dump*" -mtime +5 | xargs ls -ltrh`

Please assume in the case of the top example that it's being ran in the directory containing the files. In the second however, it can be ran from wherever. My main concern is around the filepath vs -name part; so please focus your attention that way if you can.

Apologies if this has been asked before. I tried looking, but was unable to find anything on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, `dump*` is interpreted by the shell, and expanded into matching filenames, and then passed to `find`. In effect, `find` sees:

```
find dumpa dumpb ... -type f ...
```

In the second case, no interpretation is done by the shell. `find` does the filtering. Therefore, considering the recursive nature of `find`, the second method can locate files which the first will miss.

The second method is more flexible, as you can use variables in forming the `-name`/`-path` filters, but it's tricky to get [the shell to expand a wildcard](https://askubuntu.com/q/521192/158442) in a variable. Depending on what your use case is, either would be correct, but the second can corrected to match the first in all cases (using additional `find` options, such as `maxdepth`, or `prune`), but the reverse isn't true.

Consider:

```
$ tree .
.
├── dumpa
│   └── dumpc
├── dumpb
├── dumpd
└── not-dump
    └── dumpe
$ find . -type f -name 'dump*'
./not-dump/dumpe
./dumpd
./dumpa/dumpc
$ find  dump* -type f 
dumpa/dumpc
dumpd
```

---

Also note that, if nothing matches the wildcard, the first will result in an error, but the second will succeed without any results:

```
$ find blahblah* -type f
find: `blahblah*': No such file or directory
$ find . -name 'blahblah*' -type f
$
```

I would prefer the second method because:

1. It's more flexible.
2. Less error-prone. Using wildcards where nothing matches can cause trouble. I avoid shell expansion of wildcards if I can, especially if I have a tool like `find` at hand.

And an unrelated point, skip the `xargs`:

```
find ... -exec ls -lrth {} +
```

Comment: In my case, there's no sub-directories at all. From what I'm gathering, the first is more efficient because of it's nature (expanding directly into file-names), as opposed to how find approaches it.

So, with the above in mind, do you suggest a specific method?

Comment: Then I begin to wonder if you need `find` at all. Why not `ls -ltrh dump*` directly? Too many files?

Comment: Both `xargs ls -t` and `-exec ls -t {} +` won't work correctly if `find`/`xargs` end up running several invocations of `ls` because the list is too long.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed, and given that OP is running `find` instead of `ls dump*`, I wonder if there are too many files.

Comment: There's a lot of files. Plus, I plan to switch the ls for a rm - this is why I said not to really read into my examples too much, as they are just that; examples. All I wanted to know was which one is more efficient if ran in a single directory with no sub directories.

I've noticed the issues you are highlighting are related to the ls part, which isn't what I wanted assistance with.

Comment: @Hugh-Jersey I'd need to becnhmark that. Also, consider using `find`'s `-delete`, in either case.